# twig's dump ouput loaded via $http cannot be collapsed or expanded

Tags: angularjs, http, twig, dump

I have a simple action(in Symfony 2.8 using Twig 1.23.1), that renders a string:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="my_test_route")
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function testAction() {


    $returnContent = array(
        'message'=>'my message',
        'test' => array(
            'one' => 'one',
            'two' => 'two',
            'three' => 'three',
            'four' => 'four',
            'five' => 'five',
            'six' => 'six',
        )
    );

    return $this->render('MyBundle:message.html.twig', $returnContent);
}
```

The template simply outputs the message and dumps the test array:

```
{% extends 'MyBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ dump(test) }}
    {{ message }}
{% endblock %}
```

The above scenario is working and I get the expected dump output.

[image: dump - a good version]

However when I get the output from that action using Angular's $http service, i.e.:

```
webServices.getData(ajaxUrl).then(function (response) {
    $scope[myvar] = $sce.trustAsHtml(response); 
});
```

Where the service is as follows:

```
app.factory('webServices',['$http', function($http){

    return {
        getData : function(ajaxUrl){

            return  $http.get(ajaxUrl).then(function(response) {

                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I, still get the expected output, but the dump output can no longer be collapsed or expanded and is always expanded.

[image: dump - the broken version]

Obviously with lots of data this causes an inconvenience to say the least.
And my question is what is it about the $http service(or the way I am using it) that removes the caret from the output of the dump function? Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should also mention that in the same situation, an even worst issue exists with the ladybug, where the is actually no output at all.

Comment: Specify json as your http return data type?

Comment: Thanks, Jbird, for the reply. Would you please elaborate though? The data that I am returning is html at the moment? Are you suggesting to not return html?

Comment: My thought is that $http is interpreting the response as text/html, not as an array. If the response was a json array, I'm guessing $http would interpret the response as an array. What happens if you json_encode "test" like ```dump(json_encode(test))```?

Comment: I will try that later tonight. But while I haven't: What you are saying leads me to believe that it is given that the response should be a json array and I am missusing the $http(I am new to this). I am actually expecting html code to come back and be inserted into the page that does the $http call. Is this a wrong thing to do?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying - sorry if I'm not being clear. $http is just a wrapper for Ajax requests so it is intended for html, json, xml, text. Im just thinking that if the array is encoded as json it will be inspectable like in your first example.

Comment: Got you, thanks. Will try and post the result.

Comment: I di this: {{ dump(test|json_encode()) }} and it gave me one line output of the array - a json string.

Answer (score 0):

In a HTML context the output will not be escaped correctly. You could try addslashes() in your controller but if you intend to dump html in Twig templates you must use `<pre>` tag.

Source: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your input - I will try this tonight. Thanks for your time today too. :)

Comment: Tried it with no luck. I did a bit more investigation and it looks like it's more to do with the fact that the output of the dump function contains JavaScript that is supposed to execute on page load. It creates the carret, adds event listeners and collapses the output. In Angular, I parse the response and just assign it to the angular scope variable. So I guess I need to find a way to execute it... Also it looks like the argument to the function that needs to execute contains a random number that is different for every dump output, i.e.: Sfdump("sf-dump-142700891")...